# Overriding the FOSUserBundle controllers

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

So I read alot about the overriding of templates and such and overriding of bundles in Symfony.

I am using the new Symfony 2.3, I have not tried this in lower versions of Symfony.

I followed the tutorial about overriding bundles in Symfony:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

I followed the tutorial about overriding the controllers of FOSUserBundle, which is the same thing really:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

I had a bundle named Acme/WebBundle.

Now I have done the following things:

- Created a new bundle named Acme/UserBundle.
- Created the file AcmeUserBundle.php in this bundle.

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Acme\UserBundle;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

  class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
  {
      public function getParent()
      {
          return 'FOSUserBundle';
      }
  }
  ```
- Created the following file structure:

  ```
  -src
      -Acme
          -UserBundle
              -Controller
                  RegistrationController.php
              -Entity
                  User.php
              -Resources
                  -translations
                  -views
              AcmeUserBundle.php
  ```
- In RegistrationController.php I set the namespace to:

  ```
  namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;
  ```
- Copied the contents of the registration controller of FOSUserBundle to mine.
- Added to the beginning of registerAction()

  ```
  die("message");
  ```

Now when I go to the registration form, the default /register route, I don't get a die, everything works fine. It does not see my bundle as a child, nothing is overridden and I've been trying to get it to work for ages hence my question here.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you remember to add your new UserBundle to AppKernel::registerBundles()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that you need to add any new bundle to AppKernel::registerBundles() in app/AppKernel.php like this:

```
    $bundles = array(
        ...
        new Acme\UserBundle()
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, something so small but so important.